# Mysql MATCH AGAINST - IN BOOLEAN MODE problem

Tags: mysql, search, match, against

I need to find the following string: 'c++'

My sql query look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop_product
WHERE
   MATCH(shop_product.name, shop_product.product_model, shop_product.keywords, shop_product.part_number, shop_product.upc, shop_product.brand_name)
   AGAINST ('c++' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
GROUP BY `product_id`
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This script does not return any results even if there exists records containing that word.
How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: And your columns have appropriate fulltext indexes? Are your tables MyISAM tables?

Comment: Yes, the columns are fulltext indexes, in a MyIsam table.

Answer (score 2):

Words with less than four characters are not searched in BOOLEAN MODE or NATURAL MODE.

Answer (score 1):

"+" isn't a "word" character. Probably you have to use LIKE or REGEXP.

Comment: Is there any escape character for MATCH AGAINST?

Answer (score 1):

You could search without BOOLEAN MODE:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop_product
WHERE
   MATCH(shop_product.name, shop_product.product_model, shop_product.keywords, shop_product.part_number, shop_product.upc, shop_product.brand_name)
   AGAINST ('c++'))
GROUP BY `product_id`
LIMIT 0, 25
```

I think the + is just for boolean mode a special character.

Comment: so far as I understood it it the issue is that it does not even index the `+`s. I may be completely wrong though!